# Getting error submitting app to store in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, provisioning-profile, application-loader

I have all the certificates and done the procedure for provisioning profile for submitting the app to application loader.
here is my provisoning profiles for development and distribution:
[image]

Here is my Error:
[image]

how can i solve this please help me.

Comment: Please don't post the same question multiple times

Comment: ok but i did not get any solution for this thats y i did this,please help me for solve this.